# "App Store temporary unavailable" for sandbox in app purchases

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to test in app purchases in my Mac app for the App Store but no matter what I do i keep on getting this error:

[image]

When I look at the `Console` app logs I see this:

```
2/26/13 3:08:05.452 PM App Store[1798]: FRWebDelegate: Received http status code 500 on response.
2/26/13 3:08:06.686 PM App Store[1798]: FRWebDelegate: Received http status code 500 on response.
2/26/13 3:08:07.929 PM App Store[1798]: FRWebDelegate: Received http status code 500 on response.
2/26/13 3:08:09.162 PM App Store[1798]: FRWebDelegate: Received http status code 500 on response.
2/26/13 3:08:10.401 PM App Store[1798]: FRWebDelegate: Received http status code 500 on response.
2/26/13 3:25:19.819 PM App Store[1798]: FRWebDelegate: Received http status code 500 on response.
```

My products are listed correctly and it looks like all purchasing stuff is fine but I still can't get this to work.

Has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not have been this, but once I started to use a test user with the same country as my current app store account (which is Brazil) the erros stopped hapenning.

I was trying with a user for the US app store and the store had to be switched to the US store when the app started and looks like this might make the App Store app send bad data to Apple servers.

So, create test users for the same country as your own app store account. This worked for me.